# Spring form errors from property file

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp

I'm using Spring form tag library and I want my form error messages to be
taken from some messages.properties file, I have the following jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" action="" commandName="client">    
    <form:input path="name"/><form:errors path="name">
    <input class="button" type="submit" 
        value='<fmt:message key="login.submit"/>'>
</form:form>
```

here submit button value is loaded from some message
 
source file (<fmt:message key="login.submit" />), and
 
I want my error messages to be loaded from there too, 
I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<fmt:message key='<form:errors path="name">' />
```

it simply returns ?????? value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest JSP tags as you are trying to do (although you can put a JSP tag inside a HTML tag) but AFAIK the `form:errors` tag will get the messages from the spring messageSource anyway. Try using just

```
<form:errors path="name">
```

without the `<fmt:message...` bit.